# How do you reference a function with the same name as a property?

Tags: java, jenkins, groovy

### Question

How can I reference this top-level function from within the data class? Or is Java's encapsulation of a class restrictive to the point that you cannot reach beyond the current class?

### Code

```
def String branchName() {
  return ((env.GIT_BRANCH ?: 'master') =~ /(?i)^(?:origin\/)?(.*)/)[0][1];
}

public DeployConfig implements IDeployConfig {
  public DeployConfig(IDeployConfig config) {
    this._appName = config.app;
    this._gitUrl = config.gitUrl;
    // ... et cetera
  }
  
  public String getBranchName() {
    return branchName()
  }
}
```

### Background

I'm trying to define a data class that represents our standard Jenkinsfile configuration, in an attempt to make our pipeline more testable, and less "cross your fingers and hope it didn't break anything". Toward that goal, here is a snippet of that implementation.

Now, the property getter I'm trying to write doesn't know the actual branch being built when the object is constructed, because that's derived from the `Map<String, String>` returned by `checkout scm` which gets instantiated at runtime. We assign the `GIT_BRANCH` out to the global environment `env.GIT_BRANCH` so that it can be referenced elsewhere.

### Miscellaneous

To the would-be suggestion of putting the target branch in the Jenkinsfile, that defeats the purpose of the Jenkinsfile being an instruction set for a job with Git configurations assigned, such as a multi-branch job with a shared Jenkinsfile.

### Other Code

To give some context about what I mean about the `checkout scm` command happening after the construction of `DeployConfig`, the pipeline roughly resembles this:

```
// ./pipeline-library/vars/deploy.groovy
#!/usr/bin/groovy
def call(Closure body) {
  def config = [:]
  body.resolveStrategy = Closure.DELEGATE_FIRST
  body.delegate = config
  body()

  environmentVariables(config) // assigns certain keys to global env

  if (env.IS_PROD) {
    deployProd(config)
  }
  else {
    deployNonProd(config)
  }
}

// ./pipeline-library/vars/deployNonProd.groovy
#!/usr/bin/groovy

def call(Map config) {
  // local variable declarations
  
  pipeline {
    agent { 
      label 'some-configuration-name'
    }
    
    environment {
      // shared environment variables
    }

    options {
      // configured options, like timestamps and log rotation
    }
    
    stages {
      stage('Checkout') {
        steps {
          def gitInfo = checkout scm
          env.GIT_BRANCH = gitInfo.GIT_BRANCH
        }
      }
      
      // additional stages
    }
  }
}
```

### Edits

Edit: The idea behind the property that calls the top-level function is a computed property that gets called later in the pipeline, after the `checkout scm` command has been executed. The `DeployConfig` would be constructed before the pipeline runs, and so the branch is not known at that time.

Comment: The basic problem is that you can't use `env` directly from classes or from functions called by classes. `env` isn't a real global variable, but instead is only available through the pipeline script binding. To use it in classes, you have to pass it from the pipeline to the class constructor  and store it as a class member. Then pass it as argument to `branchName()`.

Comment: @zett42 thanks for helping me understand the problem of scoping members of the calling class. I found a work-around for emulating the operation of the Jenkins pipeline environment and posted it below as an answer to would-be readers, should anyone have the same question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I solved the problem for myself, but it's arguably a less than ideal solution to the problem. Basically, here's what I had to do:

First, I created a getter `getGetBranchName` and setter `setGetBranchName` on the class of type `Closure<String>` and it had a backing field `_getBranchName`. I also created a property `getBranchName` of type `String` that returned the result of `this._getBranchName()`.

Second, if the incoming `Map` has a property `branchName`, then I set the value `this._getBranchName = () -> { return config.branchName }` so that I am referencing the getter of an outer object.

Third, as a final check, I assign the global function signature from Jenkins after constructing the `DeployConfig` object. That all looks like the below code (Note: ellipses are used to indicate more code unrelated to the specific solution):

```
import groovy.json.JsonBuilder
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper

import com.domain.jenkins.data.DeployConfig
import com.domain.jenkins.data.GitUrl
import com.domain.jenkins.exceptions.InterruptException
import com.domain.jenkins.io.FileSystem
import com.domain.jenkins.pipeline.PipelineJob
import com.domain.jenkins.pipeline.PipelineStage


class Program {
  static FileSystem fs
  static PipelineJob pipeline
  static Map<String, String> env
  static Map jenkinsfile
  
  static {
    fs = new FileSystem()
    pipeline = new PipelineJob()
    env = [:]
    jenkinsfile = [ ... ]
  }

  static String branchName() {
    return ((env.GIT_BRANCH ?: 'master') =~ /(?i)^(?:origin\/)?(.*)/)[0][1]
  }

  static void main(String[] args) {
    println 'Initialize pipeline'
    pipeline = new PipelineJob()
    println 'Initialize configuration'
    DeployConfig config = new DeployConfig(jenkinsfile)
    println new JsonBuilder(config.toMap()).toPrettyString()
    println 'Assign static method as getBranchName method'
    config.getBranchName = () -> { return branchName() }
    println 'Assign environment variables to global env'
    env << config.environmentVariables

    ...
  }
}
```

And the `DeployConfig` class accepts that using the following (Note: most of the related code is not included for brevity's sake):

```
package com.domain.jenkins.data

import com.domain.jenkins.interfaces.IDeployConfig
import com.domain.jenkins.interfaces.IMappable
import com.domain.jenkins.interfaces.Mappable

class DeployConfig extends Mappable implements IDeployConfig, IMappable {
  private Closure<String> _getBranchName

  DeployConfig() {
    this.branchName = 'master'
  }

  DeployConfig(Map options) {
    this.branchName = options.branchName
  }

  String getBranchName() {
    return this._getBranchName()
  }
  
  void setBranchName(String value) {
    if(this._getBranchName == null) {
      this._getBranchName = () -> { return 'master' }
    }
    
    if(value) {
      this._getBranchName = () -> { return value }
    }
  }
  
  void setGetBranchName(Closure<String> action) {
    this._getBranchName = action
  }
}
```

Comment: Interesting. How do you use this code from a pipeline job? I. e. where does `Program::main()` get called?

Comment: Some of this code is for a mock project. I wrote it to emulate the pipeline environment so I could write my new pipeline syntax and see if it worked as intended with a real configuration, and all of the related code areas. As such, `Program::main()` is run directly in a `Main.groovy` script at the top-level of my project. The `DeployConfig` is a prototype of a data class I want to write to improve the pipeline because, in its current incarnation, we pass a Closure to the pipeline, and each subsequent call passed another new Closure of properties, which makes tracing code a headache